# Image not showing in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an image injected into the page from a chrome extension.
When I inspect the injected element it looks like this:

```
<img src="chrome-extension://edccnohanonbgondaihhbobkmhekjlpf/images/search.png" title="search">
```

The image does not show, but instead has the standard "not found" placeholder along with the text "search" (from the title attribute).

If I right-click the value in the src attribute and select "open in new tab", it shows the image, proving that the image exists.

I have managed to get images in chrome extensions before, but for some reason, not in this one.  Are there some known limitations as to when images will work and when they wont.

I'm using:

```
chrome.runtime.getURL('images/search.png')
```

to get the image within the extension.

The difference between this extension and others is that the image is injected from a seperate source file (which is in the manifest), and called with a function call from content script (also in the manifest).

Any ideas?

Comment: It should be added to [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Comment: Thank you wOxxOm - you save me again